# add / remove class for list-view switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On a website I'm able to switch between 2 different views of shop items, 
a view with 3 columns (thumb) and a list view with 1 item per row (list).
Here is the html and script doing this

```
<ul class="filter-view">
<li>
<a href="#" id="thumb" class="thumb filter active" data-action="thumb"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" id="list" class="list filter" data-action="list"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a>
</li>
</ul>

 var list = document.querySelector('.list-section');
if (list){
    jQuery('.filter-view .filter').on('click',function(e){
        var _this = jQuery(this);
        var parent = _this.parents('.inner');
        var listContent = parent.find('.list-content');
        listContent
            .removeClass('thumb')
            .removeClass('list')
            .addClass(_this.data('action'));
        _this
            .addClass('active')
            .parent()
            .siblings()
            .find('.filter')
            .removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
};
```

I added a javascript script to realize equal height columns to the thumb-view by adding a class called "js-equal-height"
to the shop item div . Everything is working fine, but I don't
want to have this class working on the list view of the shop items.

I added the u.m. script to remove the "js-equal-height" from the list-view. The class is removed from the list view, but if I 
switch back to the thumb view the "js-equal-height" is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $('li.list.filter').hasClass('active') ) {
$('#level1').removeClass('js-equal-height');
} else {
  if ( $('li.thumb.filter').hasClass('active') ) {
 $('#level1').addClass('js-equal-height'); 
 }
 }
 });
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks
Frank

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply - no errors

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint if this contruct, means the last function should work in my case or not (sorry i am no javascript pro).

Comment: It's possible that your if statement is firing only once hence why it's not working the second time. Try attaching it to an event listener for example `$.click()` and see what happens.

Comment: Hi Raymond, thank you for your answer. I know this is not a tutorial forum here, but can you show me how to do that.

Comment: Look at your first block of code. `jQuery('.filter-view .filter').on('click',function(e){`...